# Nested React element does not appear

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to React and have the following query. Considering the code:

```
function Welcome(props:any) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
function Sous() {
    return <h3>Under</h3>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Jim" >
    <Sous/>
</Welcome>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why the browser returns only `Hello Jim` and ignores `<Sous/>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything that goes inside a component instantiation is mapped to `props.children`. You need to explicitly specify an insertion point for `children` inside `Welcome`

```
function Welcome(props:any) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.name}{props.children}</h1>;
}
```